# How can I extend the http request parameter length limitation in ESAPI?

Tags: esapi

I'm using OpenIAM as an SSO platform in my working environment.
When I try to integrate another web system that supports SAML 2.0,
I got an error saying that "the SAMLRequest parameter exceeds 2000 characters limitation"

OpenIAM support says that ESAPI has a 2,000 characters limitation in its validator and there's no way to extend it.

Is there any way to extend the limitation of HTTP request parameter length in ESAPI using .properties file or java command-line arguments so I can integrate my web applications?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug we fixed 5yrs ago ESAPI.  If OpenIAM upgrades to >= 2.2.3.1 this becomes a configurable parameter in `ESAPI.properties`

Specifically `MaxHeaderValueSize`.

The default value is 4096 which is quite liberal for most applications.  Prior to this the default size was 2000, and before that 100.  I recommend reviewing the actual need for values this large.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell me what's the parameter name?
Is it "Validator.SafeString=^[.\\p{Alnum}\\p{Space}]{0,1024}$" in the validation.properties file?

Comment: actually @jaydev, in researching to find that parameter for you, this was parameterized over 5yrs ago.  If the consuming library isn't using a more recent version of ESAPI I'd push that as there are CVEs that apply to the library as of 2016 or earlier.  

The property is `MaxHeaderValueSize` in ESAPI.properties.  The default is 4096, so I'd question why you really need a value bigger than this?

Comment: Thank you for the information. The ESAPI version OpenIAM using is 2.1.0 and the value is seemed to set to 2,000 as you mentioned. My max URL length is about 2.5K characters long, so I'd be happy with 4,096 bytes of limitation. If they're not using the ESAPI.properties file, is it OK to create the ESAPI.properties and place it to the application home directory?

Comment: If it's still set to 2000, nothing will fix that.  It was hardcoded up from 100 as a last minute "fix" before that 2.1.0 release rolled out.

Comment: You could clone the repo for 2.1.0, make the fix on the hardcode itself and replace the packaged version with your "hacked" version.  That's the only thing I can think of shooting from the hip